# Syslogd kernel:code:

Tags: crash, linux-kernel, fedora

While running some experimental Java code which interacts with a MySQL server, I received these messages and then the server crashed:

```
Message from syslogd@localhost at Jun 20 20:04:12 ...
 kernel:Stack:

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jun 20 20:04:12 ...
 kernel:Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jun 20 20:04:12 ...
 kernel:Code: e0 48 8d 55 b0 48 89 4d e8 4c 89 45 f0 48 89 45 b8 48 8d 45 d0 4c 89 4d f8 c7 45 b0 10 00 00 00 48 89 45 c0 e8 5a ff ff ff c9 c3 <89> f0 b9 40 00 00 00 55 99 45 31 c0 f7 f9 48 89 e5 48 89 fa 41
```

What do they mean? After restart, everything is working again. /var/log/messages has no entries near the time of the event and dmesg doesn't seem to show anything about it either.

Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
2.6.34.8-68.fc13.x86_64

Comment: Is it reproducible? If not, you're going to have an _extremely_ hard time finding out.

Comment: I have not tried to reproduce the error as yet, but I will when I have better physical access to the server tomorrow. If it doesn't happen again, it's not a problem, though. I am mostly concerned that the application I am testing caused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a disassembly of the dumped code, if that helps. I'm assuming the byte surrounded by the angle brackets is where the code crashed, although I can't see how a mov statement from one register to another could do so.

```
   0:   e0 48                   loopne 0x4a
   2:   8d 55 b0                lea    -0x50(%ebp),%edx
   5:   48                      dec    %eax
   6:   89 4d e8                mov    %ecx,-0x18(%ebp)
   9:   4c                      dec    %esp
   a:   89 45 f0                mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
   d:   48                      dec    %eax
   e:   89 45 b8                mov    %eax,-0x48(%ebp)
  11:   48                      dec    %eax
  12:   8d 45 d0                lea    -0x30(%ebp),%eax
  15:   4c                      dec    %esp
  16:   89 4d f8                mov    %ecx,-0x8(%ebp)
  19:   c7 45 b0 10 00 00 00    movl   $0x10,-0x50(%ebp)
  20:   48                      dec    %eax
  21:   89 45 c0                mov    %eax,-0x40(%ebp)
  24:   e8 5a ff ff ff          call   0xffffff83
  29:   c9                      leave  
  2a:   c3                      ret    
  2b:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax   <-- here is where it failed?
  2d:   b9 40 00 00 00          mov    $0x40,%ecx
  32:   55                      push   %ebp
  33:   99                      cltd   
  34:   45                      inc    %ebp
  35:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  37:   f7 f9                   idiv   %ecx
  39:   48                      dec    %eax
  3a:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  3c:   48                      dec    %eax
  3d:   89 fa                   mov    %edi,%edx
  3f:   41                      inc    %ecx
```

---

I don't know how to use any of the *grep programs to search for binary data, so you might need to write a few lines of perl or python to locate the kernel code involved. It is quite doubtful that your Java code, or anything to do with MySQL, could have caused a kernel-level crash.

---

Corrected disassembly for 64-bit mode:

```
00000000 <.data>:
   0:   e0 48                   loopne 0x4a
   2:   8d 55 b0                lea    -0x50(%rbp),%edx
   5:   48 89 4d e8             mov    %rcx,-0x18(%rbp)
   9:   4c 89 45 f0             mov    %r8,-0x10(%rbp)
   d:   48 89 45 b8             mov    %rax,-0x48(%rbp)
  11:   48 8d 45 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  15:   4c 89 4d f8             mov    %r9,-0x8(%rbp)
  19:   c7 45 b0 10 00 00 00    movl   $0x10,-0x50(%rbp)
  20:   48 89 45 c0             mov    %rax,-0x40(%rbp)
  24:   e8 5a ff ff ff          callq  0xffffff83
  29:   c9                      leaveq 
  2a:   c3                      retq   
  2b:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  2d:   b9 40 00 00 00          mov    $0x40,%ecx
  32:   55                      push   %rbp
  33:   99                      cltd   
  34:   45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
  37:   f7 f9                   idiv   %ecx
  39:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  3c:   48 89 fa                mov    %rdi,%rdx
  3f:   41                      rex.B
```

[looking at this again after all these years, I realize what the problem more likely was: a stack underflow. the `retq` had no place to return, as the stack was empty, so the instruction pointer was left pointing at the following instruction -- jc]

Comment: How would I find where these instructions were executing? It would be helpful to know even whether it is in Java or MySQL (or something else?). If you could help trace it to a specific part of the source or a class, that would help too.

Comment: it's kernel code, apparently, so Java and MySQL are not very high on the list of likelihoods. if I were to venture a guess, I wouldn't rule out cosmic radiation.

Comment: it looks like you have decoded the code as 32-bit x86 but it is probably x86_64. The question suggests this and those multiple `dec %reg` instructions are probably rather REX prefixes. If you could decode it as x86-64, the result might be diferent and it may give some hints for what happened.

Comment: agh, right. let me see if I can do that without rebooting into my 64-bit kernel.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer, I just looked at it again and figured out what I had failed to see almost 4 years ago!